# How to design a website for all screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I want to make a website which scales to window size/resolution.

Currently I am using tables which are not scaling, but instead overlap each other as I resize browser window.

What do I use in order to solve my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Your question is incredibly broad, you'll need a culmination of HTML, JavaScript, CSS, and media queries.

Comment: ok I will ask again and will be more specific. I want my tables to fit on all resolution I use <table> in html also its probably important but my text should be smaller as well on low resolution, thats all I want, hope it makes more sense now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search about *Responsive Design*, meaning the design and the implementation of a website so that it can be optimally displayed in a wide range of screen resolutions. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design) for more.

Comment: You are welcome, consider voting it as best answer if you consider it one.

Comment: I cannot vote up because I need 15 reputation but I did accept your answer if thats what you want :) Thanks again

Comment: Ok, you are welcome again.